# Gmail API html post example please

Tags: gmail-api

Sincere apologies in advance. I have looked and looked but can't find what I need here (or elsewhere). I hope you will be patient. I have some tech knowledge but not Java or Python.

I need an example of someone using HTML POST command to create a draft email. I can't use Python or Java, so the given examples and explanations aren't working.

I have the OATH bits sorted where I'm getting an access ID etc, but I don't know how to send them to the GMAIL API to create the draft email.

I feel such a noob. Can anyone please give me an example HTML code which includes setting headers correctly and creating a draft email with some html in it?

I do want to look attachments eventually but I figure I'll get to that in a later step (unless it's real easy and this can be included here).

Thanks for reading and in advance for any pointers or assistance given.

Comment: please provide the code of what you already have tried?

Comment: Please refer the below google documentation, it's including sample javascript code which can you be used for your situation

Answer (score 0):

Please refer the below google documentation, it's including sample javascript code which can you be used for your situation. (Without python or java).

https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get

JS code

```
function getMessage(userId, messageId, callback) {
  var request = gapi.client.gmail.users.messages.get({
    'userId': userId,
    'id': messageId
  });
  request.execute(callback);
}
```

For more details please refer the below article, it has complete details.

https://www.sitepoint.com/sending-emails-gmail-javascript-api/

Comment: Hi Prasan, Thank you for this. I appreciate your help.

However, I really have to use HTML post statements because of the method I'm using to call it. Is this not possible?